# Unable to load ggplot2 and dplyr

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

When i try to open ggplot2 i have the message:

> > Error : object ‘enexprs’ is not exported by 'namespace:rlang'
> >     Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggplot2’

and when i try to open dplyr I have the following message:

> > Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
> >       namespace ‘rlang’ 0.1.6 is already loaded, but >= 0.2.0 is required
> >     Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘dplyr’

I cannot update libraries, too. I'm able to download the updated versions, but still using the existing version as if I didn't do the update.

```
R version 3.3.3
RStudio version 1.1.453 
MAC OS 10.10.5
```

Any solution that doesn't include updating the OS ?

Thanks!

Comment: Try this solution https://community.rstudio.com/t/difficulty-installing-dev-version-of-ggplot2-due-to-rlang-is-list-not-being-found/8169/9

Comment: Can you also update your R version? and what version of the packages are you currently on? What happens when you run `install.packages("rlang")`? What about `devtools::install_github("r-lib/rlang")`

Comment: the next R version: 3.4 need to update the whole OS. ggplot2 version: 2.2.1.900. dplyr version 0.7.4.  installing the package using either of both commands you mentioned worked fine but still have the same problem and the `rlang` package version is not updated.

Comment: @Tung I tried using terminal session to uninstall and reinstall `rang` and `ggplot2`. ended up with this message:                                                            `The downloaded source packages are in
‘/private/var/folders/sd/cz9139jn7hv4mh069xd11flr0000gn/T/Rtmpaooys6/downloaded_packages’
Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library'
Making 'packages.html' ... done
Warning message:
In install.packages("rlang") :
  installation of package ‘rlang’ had non-zero exit status`

Comment: @Nour: can you try this portable version? https://sourceforge.net/p/rportable/news/2018/05/r-portable-version-350-and-rstudioportable-version-11447-have-been-released/

Comment: @Nour: setup your library path to point to the library location of that portable version if needed https://csgillespie.github.io/efficientR/3-3-r-startup.html#r-startup

Comment: @Tung: thanks! what do you thing the problem is ?

Comment: @Nour: I have no idea. I had `rlang` problem before but after restarting R session, and reinstalling `rlang`, everything worked like it should